# What is the context of Android Receiver defined via Manifest file?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context, android-broadcastreceiver

Say I have an Android broadcast receiver defined on the manifest file.

What is the context I received on onReceived(Context context, ...)?

Is it going to be an instance of the Application Context?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not count on it being any particular type of `Context`. It is not documented as being `Application` and could very easily be some sort of `ContextWrapper`. The actual class might even vary between Android versions.

If you need the `Application` context, call `getApplicationContext()` on the passed-in `Context`. That way, you are guaranteed to get the correct object.